# Accessing parent class slot variables

Tags: python

I'm trying to access the slot variables in a base class of an instance. So I created 2 base classes, and a single child class. Created an instance of the child class, printed the available methods and attributes on the instance. It shows the parent slot variable `slot_0` and `slot_1` are available on the child instance, But when I try to access the parent slot variable `slot_0`, it

```
class Base1():
   __slots__ = ["slot_0", "slot_1"]

   def __init__(self):
       self.slot_0 = "zero"
       self.slot_1 = "one"

   def baseFunc(self):
          print("nice1")

class Base2():
    __slots__ = []

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def baseFunc2(self):
        print("nice2")

class Child1(Base1, Base2):
    __slots__ = ["slot_00", "slot_11"]

    def __init__(self):
        self.slot_00 = "zero"
        self.slot_11 = "one"
        super()

    def newFunc(self):
        print("nice")

c1 = Child1()
print(dir(c1))
c1.slot_0
```

Updates:

1. Changed `Base2` initialization function to pass implementation
2. Called `super` in `Child1` class to call `base1` class initialization

Error:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__',
'__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__',
'__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__',
'__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__',
'__slots__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'baseFunc', 'newFunc', 'slot_0',
'slot_00', 'slot_1', 'slot_11']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Dell\Desktop\PythonPlayground\test.py", line 69, in <module>
    c1.slot_0
AttributeError: 'Child1' object has no attribute 'slot_0'. Did you mean: 'slot_00'?**
```

Comment: Your `Child1` class's `__init__()` is not calling the inherited `__init__()`s, so those attributes never get initialized.  Note that `Base2.__init__()` is invalid, because it's trying to set attributes that don't exist in `__slots__`.

Comment: I removed the initialization method implementation on Base2 class and called super() in child class. But the same problem persists, code updated!

Comment: `super()` does absolutely nothing on its own, it just gives you a way to reference a parent class's methods without having to explicitly name the parent class.  You'd need to write `super().__init__()` - but note that there is some potential confusion when combining `super` with multiple inheritance, as it may not be calling the parent class you expect.  My personal suggestion is to explicitly name the parent in such cases - `Base1.__init__(self)` for example.

Comment: Oh nevermind, you're right. The Base initialization needs to be called. THanks dude